# Please help me shorten my code

Tags: matlab, loops, matrix, command-line-arguments, repeat

**My question is to shorten repeating the process.**

> > Data1=dlmread('BadgCk-20001103-RZhS-1hAccumx10-TextData0-1.txt','\t',[31 1 286 255]);
> >
> > Data2=dlmread('BadgCk-20001103-RZhS-1hAccumx10-TextData0-1.txt','\t',[299 1 554 255]);
> >
> > Data3=dlmread('BadgCk-20001103-RZhS-1hAccumx10-TextData0-1.txt','\t',[567 1 822 255]);
> >
> > Data4=dlmread('BadgCk-20001103-RZhS-1hAccumx10-TextData0-1.txt','\t',[835 1 1090 255]);
> >
> > Data5=dlmread('BadgCk-20001103-RZhS-1hAccumx10-TextData0-1.txt','\t',[1103 1 1358 255]);
> >
> > Data6=dlmread('BadgCk-20001103-RZhS-1hAccumx10-TextData0-1.txt','\t',[1371 1 1626 255]);
> >
> > Data7=dlmread('BadgCk-20001103-RZhS-1hAccumx10-TextData0-1.txt','\t',[1639 1 1894 255]);
> >
> > Data8=dlmread('BadgCk-20001103-RZhS-1hAccumx10-TextData0-1.txt','\t',[1907 1 2162 255]);
> >
> > Data9=dlmread('BadgCk-20001103-RZhS-1hAccumx10-TextData0-1.txt','\t',[2175 1 2430 255]);
> >
> > Data10=dlmread('BadgCk-20001103-RZhS-1hAccumx10-TextData0-1.txt','\t',[2443 1 2698 255]);
> >
> > Data11=dlmread('BadgCk-20001103-RZhS-1hAccumx10-TextData0-1.txt','\t',[2711 1 2966 255]);
> >
> > Data12=dlmread('BadgCk-20001103-RZhS-1hAccumx10-TextData0-1.txt','\t',[2979 1 3234 255]);
> >
> > Data13=dlmread('BadgCk-20001103-RZhS-1hAccumx10-TextData0-1.txt','\t',[3247 1 3502 255]);

where the first 30 lines must be skipped before obtaining Data1.
      After Data1, 12 lines must be ignored for Data2 - Data13.
      Each data contains 256*255 matrix.

**Note: dlmread('myfile.txt', '\t', [R1 C1 R2 C2]);**

I would be really greatful for all your helps. 
Thank you.

Comment: Tangentially related.  I covered this coding technique yesterday in my blog:  http://blogs.mathworks.com/videos/2010/08/18/matlabdo-the-way-of-matlab/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you could use a loop and collect your data sets in a cell array, something like (not tested)

```
nData = 13;

data = cell(nData,1);

for n = 1:nData
    startPos = 31+(n-1)*268;
    endPos = 286 + (n-1)*268;

    data{n} = dlmread('BadgCk-20001103-RZhS-1hAccumx10-TextData0-1.txt','\t', [startPos 1 endPos 255]);
end
```

edit:
if you want combine all the data to one large matrix afterwards, you can use

```
dataMatrix = [data{:}]
```

you may need to transpose the result of dlmread first depending on how you want to concatenate into the final matrix

Comment: If you dont mind I would like to ask for one more thing. Say if your nData has a dimension of [1,65280]. How can I combine all of them into 1 large matrix in term of data{n}? 
For example, Data =[Data1;Data2;Data3;Data4;Data5;Data6;Data7;Data8;Data9;Data10;Data11;Data12;Data13];

Comment: What if I want to find the average of all the data:

for example,

Avg_data = (Data1+Data2+Data3+Data4+Data5+Data6+Data7+Data8+Data9+Data10+Data11+Data12+Data13)/13

Thanks again..